# Saving webView content locally to load the content offline next time

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview

**I have the following UseCase**

There is a `Fragment` which has a `WebView` inside it. When the fragment is loaded, I make an API call to the server, which returns html as the response. I want to save this response locally in the device so that next time when the fragment is loaded, I am able to immediately show the content.

I set the data to the WebView using the following code.

```
 WebView webView = // Find View By Id.
 webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

 //This function is called when response is received from the server.
 @Override
  public void showWebItem(String baseUrl, String content) {
    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(baseUrl, HtmlFontHelper.wrapDataWithHTML(content),
    Constants.HTML_MIME_TYPE,
    Constants.HTML_UTF_ENCODING, null);
}
```

**Solution to the above mentioned UseCase:**

1. Override `onPageFinished()` function of `WebViewClient`. In the `onPageFinished()` method, call `saveWebArchive()` function which will save the content of the `WebView` in a .mht format.

   ```
   private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
       @Override
       public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
           String folderName = Utils.getApplication().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/cachedFiles";
           File folder = new File(folderName);

           if (!folder.exists()) {
               folder.mkdir();
           }
           webView.saveWebArchive(folderName + "/" + "sample.mht");
       }
   }
   ```
2. When the fragment is loaded next time, check whether the .mht file exists before making the server call. If the file exists, load the content from the .mht file. Else make a server call.

   ```
   private void loadContentIntoWebView() {
       String folderName =getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/cachedFiles";
       String filename = folderName + "/" + "sample.mht";
       File file = new File(filename);

       if (file.exists()) {
           //Using loadUrl of the .mht file, I am able to load the html content.
           webItemContent.loadUrl("file://" + filename);
       } else {
           //Make Server call.
       }
   }
   ```

I am able to achieve the above mentioned functionality using the above piece of code.  But I wanted to make sure, that this is the correct way of doing it. Are there any pitfalls of using this approach? If anybody has gone through a similar usecase, please let me know.

Comment: What is **HtmlFontHelper**?